# How to change the background colour of md-card based on some condition in angular 2?

Tags: css, angular, material-design, angular-material2

I am **dynamically displaying cards** by looping through ***ngFor**. I want to update the card background color based on some condition.For e.g. If some condition satisfies, the cards background is green in colour. Else, the card background color is unchanged or changed to red color. How to achieve this dynamic behavior in Angular 2? I tried using ***ngIf**, but then the layout got messed up. I want only the background color to be changed based on the condition without affecting any layout changes. For responsive behavior I am using flex layout.

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutWrap style="padding-bottom: 25px; 
                                        padding-top: 25px;
                                        margin: auto;
                                        justify-content: center">  
    <md-card fxFlex.gt-md="45" 
             fxFlex.md="45" 
             fxFlex.sm="auto" 
             fxFlex.xs="100" 
             *ngFor="let data of myArray"
             [style.background]="'lightBlue'"
              style="margin:5px;">

        <md-card-content>
            <h1></h1>
            <h2></h2>
            <h2></h2>
        </md-card-content>
    </md-card> 
</div>
```

Comment: Try the below expression: `[ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: data.property === 'something' ? 'green' : 'red'}"`

Comment: @Lambo14 Thanks a lot...it worked

Comment: @Lambo14 How can I modify the above expression to have three conditions for the same property .Foe e.g **data.property > 'something' set colour to blue , data.property < 'something1' set colour to red, data.property < 'something2' set colour to yellow**

Comment: use the ternary operator twice i.e. [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: data.property > 'something' ? 'blue' : (data.property < 'something1' ? 'red' : 'yellow')}"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This worked as well   `[style.background]="condition ? 'lightBlue':'yellow'"`